# I can't install the google written app even though the apk I originally had was deleted

Tags: android, apk, adb

Help please

I wanted to update a game that I was playing, but it was a modded apk. I deleted the one I had and went to download the updated modded apk but it wouldn't let me because it said "app not installed as package conflicts with an existing package". At this point I'm confused because the game is nowhere in my files like it's not there AT. ALL. so by this point I'm like let me try to download it from the play store and when I went to download it from there play store said "You cannot install this app because another user has already installed an incompatible version on this device". I don't know what to do anymore I've tried the adb command thing and it fixed nothing.

Edit: The fist time I used adb I used the code `adb shell` and then did `$ pm uninstall -k --user 0 app.package` it gave me the error "failure [not installed for 0]. by this time I had already uninstalled it but play store still said it was on my phone. Then I dug around some more and found out that the "-k" meant to keep the data and whatnot so I went back and re downloaded the app on my phone using adb and then deleted using adb, tried the play store it still had the same error message. I went back to the command prompt and typed `adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 app.package` and it showed "failure [not installed for 0].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try to install the app via adb and then edit your question and include exact command you execute and the full output including error message as text.

Answer (score 0):

Try `dumpsys user` or `am get-current-user` ...and then use the correct ID of the user, instead of `0`.
PS: The personal and the work profile do have different user ID (this alone may cause confusion). Or try listing user-installed packages `pm list packages` `-u -3`?

Comment: When I typed in "am get-current-user" the output came out as "0". I saw the app when I typed in " pm list packages -u -3" , so what can I do to get rid of it?